# Apex Test Class for trigger

Tags: apex, class, unit-test

Below is my first trigger and it works! Then I found out I had to right a test class and I have no idea where to start. Please advise. Thanks!

```
trigger CreateProject on Opportunity (after update) {
    List<SFDC_Project__c> p = new list<SFDC_Project__c>();
    for (Opportunity O: Trigger.New)
        if(o.stageName == 'Closed Won'){
            SFDC_Project__c SP = new SFDC_Project__c();
            sp.name = 'CLIENT-';
            sp.total_charge__C = o.est_monthly_recurring_rev_payspan__c;
            sp.total_charge_reimbursement__c = o.est_monthly_recurring_rev_REI__c; 
            sp.project_type__c = 'Implementaion';  
            sp.Account__c = O.AccountId;
            sp.opportunity_owner__C = O.OwnerId; 
            sp.sfdc_project_manager__c = '00550000000n0VZ'; 
            sp.opportunity__c = o.id; 
            p.add(sp);
         }
    insert p;         
}
```

Comment: I went to this years session and it was great, this video is from last years testing best practices Hands On Training. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9amswhOxJw

Comment: Have you considered doing some research of your own ? This is a very broad question, which has been covered repeatedly across the internet and in the apex documentation. Please try to start and only ask specific questions when you're unsure how to test a specific scenario.  A good introduction is this one : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Answer (score 2):

There are several great resources for writing unit tests:

- [Writing Your First Apex Class and Trigger](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm)
- [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)

If you get stuck, come back with specific questions, and post the code you've written so far. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It would actually be rather simple. To get a baseline test:

```
@isTest
public class AfterUpdateOpportunityTriggerTest
{
   static testMethod void AfterUpdateOpportunityCreatesProjectsTest()
   {
      /*Create your test data and set it up for the condition you want to check for*/
      Opportunity testOpportunity = new Opportunity(/*Add all required fields here*/);
      INSERT testOpportunity;
      testOpportunity.stageName = 'Closed Won';
      UPDATE testOpportunity;

      /*Gather the records/data that would be generated after your trigger executed*/
      List<sObject> projectsCreated = [SELECT Id, /*Other fields you might check*/ 
          FROM SFDC_Project__c];

      System.assertEquals(/*Number of records you expect*/, projectsCreated.size(), 
      /*Descriptive message if your test failed*/);

      /*Assert on the other fields to check if their values are correct*/

      /*You could check them in a foreach loop*/
      for(sObject projectRecord : projectsCreated)
      {
          System.assertEquals(projectRecord.get(/*The value you expect it to be*/),
              /*field you want to check the value on*/,
              /*The error message you will see if the assert fails*/);
      }
   }
}
```

I think that's a good start.

You may want to test by inserting multiple Opportunities for better test cases. Also, a test record generator, even the simplest one can yield great benefits.

@metadaddy has linked some great resources. Be sure to check them out.

Comment: Speaking of a test record generator check out this: (SEED for Test Methods) https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5WBZEA3 - looks promising